# Avoid CreateMap while mapping source and destination of same class

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

Is there a way I can avoid `Mapper.CreateMap<UserDetail, UserDetail>()`?

I want to do

```
_dbContext.UserDetails.ById(Id).ProjectTo<UserDetail>().SingleAsync()
```

but this doesn't work unless I add

```
Mapper.CreateMap<UserDetails, UserDetails>();
```

Is there any feature  provided by automapper to accomplish this without having to add the `.CreateMap()`?

Comment: Why would you project to the same type? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yeah I figured it was stupid. Thank you anyway! @LucianBargaoanu

Comment: @PriyankaB Did you actually have a reason to do this? It's certainly possible there is a reason that I am not thinking of, and I'm curious.

Comment: @CollinM.Barrett yes I did. I wanted to avoid the .Include() (s) for the query for some child elements, and wanted to try the .Project<UserDetail>(), since it maps the child elements as well. But it adds 2 objects to the dbContext tracker. So I skipped this part and went with the .Include() for this query. Thank you for asking!